# Azure Data Factory - skipped rows with empty collection reference when flattening JSON

Tags: arrays, json, azure-data-factory

I am trying to serialize the following JSON to Parquet using ADF Copy Activity:

```js
[
    {
        "mac": "06A1E8A75834",
        "timestamp": "2020-11-06T00:00:00+02:00",
        "floor_number": 2,
        "x": 300.00,
        "y": 350.00,
        "located_inside": true,
        "zones": [
            {
                "zone_map_name": "sections",
                "zone_name": "z_1_"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "mac": "06A1E8A75835",
        "timestamp": "2020-11-06T00:00:00+02:00",
        "floor_number": 2,
        "x": 300.00,
        "y": 300.00,
        "located_inside": true,
        "zones": []
    }
]
```

However in some cases the zones array is empty and the rest of the record is skipped.
The expected behavior is when the array is empty - the zone_name and zone_map_name are empty.

The mapping looks like this:
[image: mapping]

Is there a way to tell ADF how to treat empty collection reference as empty values in rows?

Comment: The described behavior is now added to official documentation in this section:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#tabular-source-to-tabular-sink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know, ADF will skipped rows with empty collection reference when flattening JSON.
When we uncheck that box.
[image]

ADF will copy all the items to destination, like this:

```
[{"mac":"06A1E8A75834","timestamp":"2020-11-06T00:00:00+02:00","floor_number":2,"x":300.0,"y":350.0,"located_inside":true,"zone_map_name":"sections","zone_name":"z_1_"}
,{"mac":"06A1E8A75835","timestamp":"2020-11-06T00:00:00+02:00","floor_number":2,"x":300.0,"y":300.0,"located_inside":true}
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just a small additional question - maybe you are aware if there is any description of this behavior in Microsoft docs? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I have not found any explanation for this. It seems that it determines whether to allow copying of null values to destination.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the confirmation! I will then try to file a pull request for the official documents to mention this behavior.